# CakePHP 2.0 AuthComponent use own column name

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

how i can use following. 
i have columns in my table wf_users: `wf_username, wf_password` now in my form i don´t wanna anyone to se my table structure therefore i use in my Form

`$this->Form->input("username")­;`
and not the 
`$this->Form->input("wf_username")­;`
 my post looks like this

`User=>array( 'username', 'password' );`

now i need them to change into my named column or that want do the trick to login in the allowed area because it try´s to fetch with wrong column (with `"username"` not with `"wf_usernam"`).

My AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $viewClass = 'Theme';

    public $theme;

    public $components = array(
                            'Auth'=> array(
                                'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'dashboard'),
                                'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'dashboard'),
                                'authError'=>'yout can´t access the page!',
                                'authorise'=>array('Controller'),
                                #'authenticate' => array(
                                #   'Form' => array(
                                #       'fields' => array(
                                #           'wf_auth_user_username' => 'username',
                                #           'wf_auth_user_password' => 'password'
                                #       )
                                #   )
                                #)
                            ),
                            'Session'
                         );

    //Before mainlayout
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->theme = 'SM';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username'=>'wf_auth_user_username','password'=>'wf_auth_user_password');
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        //Logged in user
        $this->set('isauth', 'loggedout'); //$this->userpanelAuth());
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    protected function userpanelAuth() {
        if($this->isAuthorized()) {
            return 'loggedin';  
        }else{
            return 'loggedout';
        }
    }

}
```

And This is my Form:

```
                            <div id="display-panel">
                                <?
echo $this->Session->flash();

                                        echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
                                        echo $this->Form->input(
                                            'username', 
                                                array('label'=>false, 'div'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Benutzername',''));
                                        echo $this->Form->input(
                                            'password', 
                                                array('label'=>false, 'div'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Passwort'));

                                        echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'login','div'=>false));
                                ?>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Auth component allows you to specify different fields when setting up the configuration. In this case you're using the `Form` authentication handler, which has a `fields` key.

```
<?php
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth'=> array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

From the [2.0 Authentication docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html?highlight=auth#configuring-authentication-handlers).

Comment: i tried this too same problem.

could i use this like this

public $components = array(
    'Auth'=> array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('wf_username' => 'username')
            )
        )
    )
);

Comment: should be `array( 'fields' => array('username' => 'wf_username') )`

Comment: Yeah, they to be in the reverse order from your code posted above, like Stoosh's comment. 'username' and 'password' are keys that point to the custom names you want. You can see how it's used in the `FormAuthenticate` class here: http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/form-authenticate#line-48

Comment: Note too that you don't need the `$this->Auth->fields` in the `beforeFilter()` with this method.

Comment: @brism ok the `FormAuthenticate` helped me well. and thanks @Stoosh
but i still having issues. but this thema downwards therefore i write it downwards...

Answer (score 0):

When you set all your Auth settings (usually in a beforeFilter callback) just set the `fields` property

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'wf_username', 'password' => 'wf_password');
```

Comment: it´s not working everytime i get this when i am trying

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.username' in 'where clause'

because it try it again to fetch with username which is posted to the controller and not with my wf_username...

i set it in AppController under the method "beforeFilter" how you explain

Comment: In the Users controller, if you have a beforeFilter method you need to make sure to have `parent::__beforeFilter()` in there otherwise the AppController method will not run

Comment: Apologies, seems like Cake has changed the Auth syntax for version 2.0, see brism's answer below

Comment: i post my code below this is not working can´t explain what i am doing wrong because i try both of them and both doesn´t work

Comment: ok it works but only if i use in my input also the wf_username and wf_password but that i do not want i want in my form a masked data post data[User][username] and not data[User][wf_username], how to solve this

Comment: In your login method before you call $this->Auth->login(); I guess you could change the key, `$this->request->data['User']['wf_username'] = $this->request->data['User']['wf_username']; unset($this->request->data['User']['username'];`

Comment: that doesn´t work i can print it out and get it but the authlog don´t get it. I do that in the beforeFilter, where should i change the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use those column names, wf_.  Stick to convention and stop wasting time.

Comment: it is an example to not show the table structure, event if the table have a column "name" instead of "username"